# Tableau Extract API return "Server did not call back us"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tableau-api

I try to extract in tde file Tableau Extract API and it returned error  "Server did not call back us"

```
val fileName = "1233.tde"
var extract : Extract = new Extract(fileName)
```

return exception server did not call us back
error code : 204

How to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set correct file permissions on `tdeserver64` file located in 
`site-packages/dataextract/bin/` folder.

Try to give it 755 permissions.